# На странице "Что такое Мета и как она работает?" сломана разметка

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, справка

На странице [**"Что такое Мета и как она работает?"**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) была предпринята попытка вставить ссылку на метку Меты.

Но попытка провалилась, вместо этого на странице красуется:

```
[meta-tag:предложение]
```

**[В справочном центре на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)** вместо таких конструкций используются самые обычные ссылки.

---

Также в нижней части указаны англоязычные названия меток, их стоит поменять на русскоязычные.

Comment: Есть такое. Постараюсь отредактировать в ближайшее время.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправлено.

- meta-tag:предложение на нормальную ссылку
- перевод ссылок в нижней части
- починил ссылку на FAQ
- мелкие правки опечаток и пунктуации

Всё дело в том, что в справке, как и на основном сайте, не рендерится разметка для меток Меты. То есть `[meta-tag:предложение]` не превращается в [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).